# Comparative with a clause

Tags: adjectives

How does one form a comparative sentence that has a clause in it? For comparative with adjectives the particle *ol* connects the two elements that are being compared, but when one of the compared elements is a sentence, should *ol* be used too? For example, how would you say: 'It was better than I had expected'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [sentence from Tekstaro](http://www.tekstaro.com/pl/prenitutantekston.pl?nomo=la-kiso&id=ai99&ignorifremdajhojn=1&uskle=0&serchesprimo=est.s%20pli%20%5Cw%2B%2C%3F%20ol%20.i%20%5Cw%2Bs#ai99) that may be useful to answer your question (emphasis are mine):

> Tuj mi seniĝis de la vestoj, saltis en la akvon kaj naĝis for. Sed
>   **estis pli malvarme ol mi atendis**, kaj mi ne restis longe en la lago.

Translation:

Immediately I got rid of the clothes, jumped into the water and swim away. 
But it was colder than I (had) expected, and I did not stay long in the lake.

This is a possible translation:

*It was better than I had expected.* ==> *Estis pli bone ol mi atendis.*